# porting vector<fooType> foo[num] to windows (no C99)

Tags: c++, arrays, windows, vector, stl

Can we dynamically allocate

```
std::vector<fooType> foo[num];
```

like this?

```
 std::vector<sidType>* lSamplesPerClass = new vector<sidType>[nClasses];
 [...]
 delete [] lSamplesPerClass;
```

Comment: You can, but there's very little reason to.

Comment: Just use a vector of vectors?

Comment: What does this have to do with porting to windows and C99?

Comment: @juanchopanza I believe it's legal within C99, but I'm porting to Windows and MSVC does not support it, am I right?

Comment: @juanchopanza if `num` is not a compile-time constant, C++ forbids it being used as the size of an array. This requires the C99 VLA language feature, not implemented in MSVC.

Comment: @quimnuss if you are wtiting standards compliant C++, then it doesn't matter, because VLAs are not allowed in the current standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can (assuming you really want an array of `vector`s). However, it will be safer and easier to manage if you do this instead:

```
std::vector<std::vector<fooType> > foo(num);
```

Never do dynamic allocation yourself if the standard library can do it for you.

Comment: I agree it's error-prone, but since we will know num (although not at compile time), it makes (kind of) sense, ...and the client prefers it that way. I'll take the Yes and be careful.

Comment: @quimnuss How can the client prefer `new`/`delete` over `std::vector`? He's not writing the code *for* you, is he?

Comment: @quimnuss In that case, you should at least consider using [`boost::scoped_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_array.htm) instead of a raw pointer to get exception safety.

Comment: @rubenvb It's complicated ;)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do :

```
std::vector<sidType> lSamplesPerClass = new vector<sidType>[nClasses];
[...]
delete [] lSamplesPerClass;
```

`lSamplesPerClass` shall be a pointer to `std::vector<sidType>`. You need to change it to :

```
std::vector<sidType>* lSamplesPerClass = new vector<sidType>[nClasses];
[...]
delete [] lSamplesPerClass;
```

As other suggested, it is much better to use vectors of vectors instead.

However, if you want to have one single std::vector the is dynamically allocated itself, you may want to do this :

```
std::vector<sidType>* lSamplesPerClass = new vector<sidType>(nClasses);
[...]
delete lSamplesPerClass;
```

(it is unclear in your question to see what you want to achieve)